# Visited/Unvisited link colours are too similar

Tags: feature-request, bug, design

Not sure if this is a bug, or maybe an improvement opportunity, but with my current settings I find the colours to be similar enough to cause confusion, I haven't experienced this in other sites. Could this be changed a little?

The visited link is the one from meta (congrats BTW).

[image]